# Melhor formato para trabalhar com soma de dinheiro em android

Tags: android

Estou com alguns problemas ao realizar somas de valores decimais em minha aplicação, as variações que ocorrem não são de grande diferença, mas como estou lidando com valores totais de dinheiro, precisaria que as somas não viessem quebradas em dízimas.

Pude ir atrás de algumas informações do motivo pelo qual isso ocorre, e em alguns artigos em inglês encontrei o termo utilizado *Floating-Point Arithmetic* e com uma explicação traduzida por mim a seguir:

> Por que os meus números, como 0,1 + 0,2 não resultam em uma soma com um arredondamento agradável de 0,3 mas em vez disso, obtemos um resultado estranho como 0,30000000000000004 ou 0,29999999999999999?
>
> Porque internamente, os computadores usam um formato (binário de ponto flutuante) que não pode representar com precisão um número como 0,1, 0,2 ou 0,3 em seu todo.
>
> Quando o código é compilado ou interpretado, o "0.1" já é arredondado para o número mais próximo nesse formato, o que resulta em um pequeno erro de arredondamento, mesmo antes do cálculo acontecer.

PS: A citação foi resumida para um entendimento mais fácil, tendo noção de que a explicação original para tal é mais complexa.

Utilizava a formatação double para a soma dos meus valores, onde encontrei vários erros de arredondamento, após isso mudei para float onde pude ter uma precisão melhor. Tendo em mente esses acontecimentos gostaria de confirmar se existe algum formato para trabalhar com dinheiro que apresentem uma precisão maior que o float.

Para quem quiser se aprofundar na questão, segue um link para um artigo que explica de forma bem completa e complexa:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe.

Procure trabalhar com a classe [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), que foi projetada para esse tipo de situação.

É melhor que trabalhar com `float` ou `double`.